# [fbml] vs. [facebook-fbml] on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Aren't the tags [fbml](/questions/tagged/fbml) and [facebook-fbml](/questions/tagged/facebook-fbml) referring to the same topic? It's somewhat hard to tell since both have no description. However, [facebook-fbml](/questions/tagged/facebook-fbml) only has ~40 questions, which mostly are also tagged with [fbml](/questions/tagged/fbml).

Isn't there a general rule for creating/merging tags to avoid such duplicates?

Comment: There is a suggested synonym for the fbml tag http://stackoverflow.com/tags/fbml/synonyms

Comment: @Barry: Well, a synonym is another name for something. However, SO treats them as entirely different tags. In other words, looking for either tag should return the same number of questions IMHO.