# Merge [facebook-fbml] into [fbml]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [[fbml] vs. [facebook-fbml] on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75309/fbml-vs-facebook-fbml-on-stack-overflow)

[facebook-fbml](/questions/tagged/facebook-fbml) x 77

[fbml](/questions/tagged/fbml) x 596

And both tags are meant for same purpose of [Facebook markup language](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/). And strange thing is that both tags are  sponsored tags. Why don't we merge [facebook-fbml](/questions/tagged/facebook-fbml) into [fbml](/questions/tagged/fbml) or give Synonyms?